# How to store area of each quad mesh from a mesh?

Tags: mesh

Somewhere knows how to store the area from each triangle/quad from a mesh into a txt file or something like that in Blender instead of simply showing it?
(It is possible to show all the areas doing Display -> Face info Area, but I dont know how to save all the measurements it provides)

Thanks a lot!!!

B.

Comment: so you are trying to get a list with the area of each face?

Comment: Yes, that is it ! also the angles of each face ....but I dunno how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To output the areas of each face to a file, you would need to use a python script. It is easy to use python to [create and write to a file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). You can use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to control how the data looks in the file.

The [area](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MeshPolygon.html#bpy.types.MeshPolygon.area) is a property of each face in the objects [mesh data](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.polygons), faces are called polygons here.

```
import bpy

with open('face_data.txt','w') as out_file:
    for f in bpy.context.object.data.polygons:
        out_file.write('{}, {}\n'.format(f.index, f.area))
```

Comment: Oh, yes,thanks! it works but once I create something similar just changing the format it gives me this kind of error:
AttributeError _ Restrict Context has no attribute object
and my data is not stored inside the txt file
any suggestion? I dont have any idea in how it works in blender....

Comment: The restricted context sounds like you are trying to enable an addon and have the code run before the addon is registered. You can find some info [here](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/API_Changes). Probably best to ask another question with your script to get help.

Comment: Thank you Sambler for your prompt answer, gonna check it out!